# Is there an option to turn existing global variant to constant in MySQL or MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to prevent changing some global variables which I set from the ini file.

For example:

```
server_audit_logging=ON
```

I want to prevent it from changing by:

```
SET GLOBAL server_audit_logging = OFF;
```

Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Revoke SUPER privilege needed to execute SET GLOBAL statement. See [SUPER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) and [SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_system-variables-admin).

Comment: @Akina - If `SUPER` was `GRANTed` via `ALL PRIVILEGES`, the only way to `REVOKE` is to `REVOKE ALL`, then add back the allowed privs.

Comment: @RickJames And? there is a task which must be solved. If it needs to do all described it must be done.

Answer (score 0):

Which values are you concerned about?

- Some are `GLOBAL` only.  `my.ini` and a restart is needed to change them from outside.  Or a user with `SUPER` can change them from a connection.
- Some are `SESSION`, but *initialized* to the corresponding `GLOBAL` when *you* connected.  You can override these with `SET SESSION ...`.  Once you have done that, no one else can change them until you disconnect.

If you are having trouble with a user, that is a personnel problem.  Don't give him `SUPER`.